# Trying to prove that the first derivative of dirac's delta function is odd.

Tags: calculus, analysis, dirac-delta

I'm trying to prove the oddness of $\delta'(x)$, I have managed to show that $\int \delta'(x)f(x) dx$ vanishes if f(x) is an even function, which shows $\delta'(x)$ is an odd distribution.
However, if I integrate directly, I get
$\int \delta'(x)f(x)dx = -\int \delta(x)f'(x)dx$
And
$\int\delta'(-x)f(x)dx = f(x)\int\delta'(-x)dx - \int f'(x)\int\delta'(-x)dx dx$

Now the problem is in this part

$\int\delta'(-x)dx = \int-\frac{d}{du}\delta(u)du = -\delta(u)$
I'm unsure whether this last part is true, it seems kinda fishy to turn the derivative $\frac{d}{dx}$ to $\frac{d}{du}$ when I apply the change of variable $u = -x$
Is this correct? Is there a better way to approach this?
Thanks for reading.
Edit: Assume the integrals are from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

Comment: Sorry, can you be precise? What do you mean for $\delta'$ to be odd, if it does not mean to be an odd distribution?

Comment: I am trying to prove that it's an odd distribution, but through integration by parts and treating it like a function, which sounds fishy now that I think about it. Is this approach entirely invalid?

Comment: Oh, it seems that you are asking if change of variables works when you have the dirac delta? Yes, in fact you should use $\langle T\circ \phi, f\rangle = \langle T , f\circ \phi^{-1} (\phi^{-1})'\rangle$ as a definition for nice change of variables (linear ones count), this can be extended from nice smooth functions the same way you define $d/dx$, the Fourier transform, etc

Comment: Thanks, should I withdraw the question?

Comment: i think you can leave it, maybe you can write the details of the extension or someone else will

Comment: in light of the answer you received and the comment thread i of course should have written $|(\phi^{-1})’|$ ie the correct formula is the one for Lebesgue integration

Comment: Given that $\delta(x)$ is even, can chain rule be applicable? $\frac{d}{dx}\delta(x)=-\frac{d}{dx}\delta(-x)$

Answer (score 1):

Let's denote by $g$ the reflection operator, i.e., $g(x)= -x$. $\delta^{'}$ is said to be odd if $\delta^{'} \circ g= - \delta ^{'}$ in the sense of distribution, i.e., if $\langle \delta^{'} \circ g, f \rangle = - \langle \delta ^{'}, f \rangle$ for any test function $f$ (see page 70 in [here](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Estein/lehre/SoSem09/distrvo.pdf)) . This is satisfied by $\delta^{'}$. Allowing an abuse of notation:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int (\delta ^{'} \circ g) \; f \; dx &= \int \delta ^{'}(-x) f(x) \; dx \\
& =  \int \delta ^{'} (f \circ g) dx \\
& = - \int \delta  (f \circ g)^{'} dx \\
& = + \int \delta(x)  f {'} (-x) dx \\
& = f^{'}(0) \\
\end{aligned}
$$
where we used the chain rule in in third equality. The right-hand-side reads:
$$
\begin{aligned}
-\langle \delta^{'} , f \rangle &= -\int \delta^{'} (x) f (x) dx \\
&= \int \delta (x) f^{'} (x) dx \\
& = f^{'}(0)
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence the derivative of the dirac delta is odd.

Comment: Your answer is a bit unclear because $\delta'$ is odd means that $\delta'(-x)=-\delta'(x)$ ie. $\langle \delta',f\rangle=-\langle \delta',f(-x)\rangle$

Comment: @reuns exactly. There is no meaning of $\delta ^{'} (-x)$ or $\delta ^{'} (x)$. You cannot evaluate them at points. That's why one invokes the notion of composition with the reflection function. See page 70 of the reference I cited.

Comment: $T(-x)$ is the distribution $\langle T(-x),f\rangle=\langle T,f(-x)\rangle$

Comment: In particular $\langle \delta^{'} \circ g, f \rangle = - \langle \delta ^{'}, f \circ g \rangle$ is wrong

Comment: $\langle \delta^{'}  \circ g, f \rangle = - \langle \delta^{'} , f \circ g^{-1}  \rangle$ but the inverse of the reflection function is the reflection function hence the relation is correct.

Comment: No, it is $\langle T \circ g, f \rangle =  \langle T, f \circ g \rangle$ for any distribution, approximate $T$ by an integrable function and do a change of variable in the integral.

Comment: Well, ok. Take $ ∈ ^{1} _\text{loc} (\mathbb{R})$ then: $\langle T \circ g , f \rangle = \int T(-x) f(x) dx = - \int T(y) f(-y) \; dy = -\langle T, f \circ g \rangle = -\langle T, f \circ g^{-1} \rangle $

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty T(-x)f(x)dx=\int_{\infty}^{-\infty} T(y)f(-y)d(-y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} T(y)f(-y)dy$

Comment: You are correct. I'm sorry for the confusion. I still believe the definition I wrote is the same as the one provided in literature and the literature does say that $\delta ^{'}$ is indeed odd. I'll try to fix the answer. Otherwise I'll delete it.

Comment: My definition did have a flow after all. I modified the definition and computation. I think it should be fine now (at least it should be in accordance to the definition in the reference).

Answer (score 1):

Define $P:C_c^\infty \to C_c^\infty$ by $(P\varphi)(x)=\varphi(-x).$ Note that, by the chain rule, $(P\varphi)'(x) = -\varphi'(x).$

For $\varphi,\psi\in C_c^\infty,$
$$
\langle P\varphi, \psi \rangle
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P\varphi(x) \, \psi(x) \, dx
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \varphi(-x) \, \psi(x) \, dx
= \{ x := -y \}
= \int_{+\infty}^{-\infty} \varphi(y) \, \psi(-y) \, (-dy)
\\
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \varphi(y) \, \psi(-y) \, dy
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \varphi(y) \, P\psi(y) \, dy
= \langle \varphi, P\psi \rangle.
$$
Therefore we extend $P$ to distributions by for $u\in\mathcal{D}'$ setting
$\langle Pu, \varphi \rangle = \langle u, P\varphi \rangle.$
We call a distribution *odd* iff $Pu=-u.$

Now,
$$
\langle P(\delta'), \varphi \rangle
= \langle \delta', P\varphi \rangle
= -\langle \delta, (P\varphi)' \rangle
= -(P\varphi)'(0)
= -(-\varphi'(0))
= -\langle \delta, -\varphi' \rangle
= -\langle \delta', \varphi \rangle,
$$
so $P(\delta') = -\delta',$ i.e. $\delta'$ is odd.