# How can the derivative of the dirac delta function of (-x) equal the negative derivative of the dirac delta function of x?

Tags: calculus, hilbert-spaces, dirac-delta

On the wikipedia page for the Dirac delta function derivative ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Distributional_derivatives currently by citation 50), It says that $$\delta'(-x) = -\delta'(x)$$

I'm not sure how this is possible. Because by definition of the derivative of the Dirac delta function: $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta'(x)f(t)dt = -f'(x)$$

Meaning that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta'(-x)f(t)dt = -f'(-x)$$

But if $$\delta'(-x) = -\delta'(x)$$ is a true statement, then that would mean that
$$-f'(-x) = f'(x)$$

Which is clearly not true for all functions.

Comment: The definition you wrote for the derivative of a Dirac delta is not correct. ⟨′,⟩=−′(0). The calculations you're looking for are provided in answers to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4097610/trying-to-prove-that-the-first-derivative-of-diracs-delta-function-is-odd

Comment: @Saleh
I'm sorry, I'm not as familiar with bra-ket notation. Where did I mess up on the definition of the derivative? I thought I was following the wikipedia equation (the second one down, saying "The first equality here is a kind of integration by parts")

Comment: $\int_{-\infty} ^{\infty} \delta^{'}(x) f(x) \ dx = - \int_{-\infty} ^{\infty} \delta(x) f^{'}(x) \ dx =  - f^{'}(0)$ and not $-f^{'} (x)$ as you wrote. As written in Wikipedia, first equality is a kind of integration by parts and second equality follows from definition of dirac delta. More generally, for a shifted Dirac delta you have: $\int_{-\infty} ^{\infty} \delta^{'}(x-x_0) f(x) \ dx = - f^{'}(x_0)$

Answer (score 2):

You are making a confusion between $\delta(x) = \delta_0(x)$, which is the Dirac delta distribution (centered at $0$) $\delta = \delta_0$ seen as a "function" of the $x$ variable, and $\delta_x$, which is the Dirac delta centered at the point $x$.

They are defined as measures by the formulas for any nice function $\varphi$
$$
\langle \delta,\varphi\rangle = \int_{\Bbb R} \varphi(y)\,\delta(\mathrm d y) = \int_{\Bbb R} \varphi(y)\,\delta_0(\mathrm d y) = \varphi(0)
\\
\langle \delta_x,\varphi\rangle = \int_{\Bbb R} \varphi(y)\,\delta_x(\mathrm d y) = \varphi(x).
$$
The derivatives of these measures are no longer measures but distributions, so one should not use the notation $\int f\,\varphi$ but only $\langle f,\varphi\rangle$ (but you can think of them as being the same object) and then
$$
\langle \delta'(-x),\varphi\rangle = \langle \delta',\varphi(-x)\rangle = -\langle \delta,(\varphi(-x))'\rangle
\\
= \langle \delta,\varphi'(-x)\rangle = \varphi'(0) = \langle \delta,\varphi'\rangle = -\langle \delta',\varphi\rangle
$$
so $\delta'(-x) = -\delta'(x)$. As you can see, it is due to the fact that $\varphi'(0) = \varphi'(-0)$. Of course this is no longer valid for $\delta_x$.